# Cumany function applied on NA values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following vector:

```
x <- c(FALSE,FALSE,NA,TRUE,FALSE)
```

I use the `cumany()` function to see if there is **at least** one `TRUE` value within a window of the first element up to each element in the vector or in other words in the window [1, 1:length(x)].

```
library(dplyr)
cumany(x)
[1] FALSE FALSE    NA    NA    NA
```

The output surprises me. I would expect the cumany function to work as following

```
for(i in 1:length(x)){
  print(any(x[1:i]))
}
```

Therefore I would expect an output as following

```
[1] FALSE FALSE    NA   TRUE   TRUE
```

How is the `cumany()` function defined when it comes to `NA` values?

**Update:**

This was a bug in previous `dplyr` versions and has been corrected. Just update the package if you have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question about *how is implemented* we need to dive into the implementation, which is done in C++.

As you can see below, the vector is initialized with `NAs`, however there is a crucial line of code which propagates an information if at least one `TRUE` value was met before `NAs`

```
out[i] = current || out[i - 1];
```

There is a brief [discussion](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/408) about expected behaviour on GitHub.

If your result is different from what you expected than there is a high chance that you need to update the `dplyr` package.

For more implementation details see this code below:

```
LogicalVector cumany(LogicalVector x) {
  int n = x.length();
  LogicalVector out(n, NA_LOGICAL);

  int current = out[0] = x[0];
  if (current == NA_LOGICAL) return out;
  if (current == TRUE) {
    std::fill(out.begin(), out.end(), TRUE);
    return out;
  }
  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    current = x[i];
    if (current == NA_LOGICAL) break;
    if (current == TRUE) {
      std::fill(out.begin() + i, out.end(), TRUE);
      break;
    }
    out[i] = current || out[i - 1];
  }

  return out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the underlying code. However, I still wonder about the logic of the `cumany()` function. 
No matter how many `NAs` the vector contains, as soon as there is one `TRUE`, the `any` function should return `TRUE`. Therefore, I would also expect from a cumulative `any` function to return `TRUE` as soon as there is one `TRUE` in the evaluated window. Additionally, in the vignettes about window functions in dplyr it is said `cumany()` is the cumulative version of `||`. `NA || TRUE` returns `TRUE`.

Comment: Interestingly there is a unit test on GitHub, that seems to expect the behaviour based on `NA || TRUE`. Also there is a brief [discussion](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/408) about this topic, which results in the same conclusion.

Comment: I don't know why I missed the line `out[i] = current || out[i - 1];`.  I've double-checked it and the function works as it should. Try updating `dplyr` package, maybe this is the case... sorry for the mistake, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to `replace` the `NA` with FALSE, do the `cumany` and use `|` to get the original NA fill the position

```
cumany(replace(x, is.na(x), FALSE))|x
#[1] FALSE FALSE    NA  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

To rewrite it in all base R,

```r
Reduce(any, x, accumulate = TRUE) | x
#> [1] FALSE FALSE    NA  TRUE  TRUE
```